# Windows stuck in reboot loop after moving and resizing partitions in gparted

Tags: windows, boot, gparted, recovery

I was running low on space on my C drive, so I shrank my linux /home partition, leaving around 30gb of free space. This, however, was adjacent to a 16mb windows reserved partition. I moved this partition to the left of the unallocated space, and extended the partition on which my c drive was on to the left. Both operations seemed to have been completed successfully according to gparted, so I rebooted. (I use the refind bootloader) and booted into windows. The logo and loading circle popped up for around 5 seconds, and then shut off and restarted. This time I went into bios and booted into the windows entry directly but to no avail, the exact same thing happened.

Since then I've tried prepared a windows repair usb, tried bootrec and chkdsk. It outputs the operation was successful, after rebooting I get the usual windows recovery screen, restart again and it hasn't fixed the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX5MQ.jpg

Comment: Best bet might be to restore the disk from the last complete image.

Comment: Never use gparted on Windows partitions and don't move essential boot partitions without taking a disk image backup. You might try to reproduce the previous situation *exactly* if you don't have such a backup.